# Add badge on icon launcher when receiving notification from firebase cloud messaging flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, badge

I'm using [flutter_app_badger](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger) packages to add a badge on the icon launcher when receiving notification from `firebase`. But it just works on `onMessage`. Any solution? thanks.

mycode:

```
    fcm.configure(
  
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
print("onMessage: $message");
FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);


},
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
  },
);
```

Comment: Please post the code for `myBackgroundMessageHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this line: `FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);` in the `myBackgroundMessageHandler` callback, then you can follow the steps outline in this [issue](https://github.com/g123k/flutter_app_badger/issues/31#issuecomment-785109919):

> 1. Add this method to Application.kt
>
>    ```
>    FlutterAppBadgerPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("fr.g123k.flutterappbadger"))
>    ```
> 2. [Add] this import to Application.kt
>
>    ```
>    import fr.g123k.flutterappbadger.FlutterAppBadgerPlugin
>    ```
>
> [Source](https://github.com/g123k/flutter_app_badger/issues/31#issuecomment-785109919)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, in the myBackgroundMessageHandler callback is just like what your assuming about. Thanks for the answer, I'll follow your suggestion and gonna let you know if it working. Appreciate it. @Victor Eronmosele